# CarrierWave S3 Permission denied error trying to read from the tmp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Using CarrierWave and Amazon S3.
CarrierWave config:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
      config.ensure_multipart_form = false

      config.permissions = 0777      
      config.s3_access_key_id = 'secret_access_key_id'
      config.s3_secret_access_key = 'secret_access_key'
      config.s3_bucket = 'backet_name'
 end
```

I get a permission denied error trying to read from the tmp directory when uploading to s3.

```
Errno::EACCES

Permission denied - D:/MyDirectory/public/uploads/tmp/20110211-1021-3252-6545/my_file.txt.
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this issue using Heroku, and solved it by changing the cache directory in the uploader.

```
def cache_dir
  "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
end
```

Comment: Exactly.  You can't access the public directory like he was trying to do `D:/MyDirectory/public/uploads...`

Comment: For an explanation, and some links to examples, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9877639/664833).