# Rails - Errno::EACCES (Permission denied) when uploading avatar for user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, carrierwave

I have:

- heroku
- rails 3
- carrierwave

On localhost uploading works fine. But it doesnt work on heroku.
My logs are:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 13ms
Errno::EACCES (Permission denied - /app/public/uploads/tmp):
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:73:in `update'
cache: [POST /users/2] invalidate, pass
```

My 73 line is:

```
if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

Tryed to make [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8857093/1227782) om local computer and push to heroku and failed

What else can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't store files on Heroku's servers, so uploading and trying to save files to the local filesystem will not work.

Instead, you should probably upload files to S3. The [Heroku documentation](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) and [CarrierWave documentation](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) both have information on configuring CarrierWave to upload files to S3 via fog. Check out the documentation, get an S3 account, and upload your files there.

Answer (score 0):

When you push to Heroku your app is compiled into a slug that runs on a read-only filesystem - so you cannot write to it whatsoever (i.e. you cannot even write to your own app's `public` directory). To [make Carrierwave work on Heroku](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Make-Carrierwave-work-on-Heroku), you must set the `cache_dir` in your `Uploader` class. Have a look a [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5484973/664833), and particularly the comment that says "These two lines fixed it":

```
config.root = Rails.root.join('tmp')
config.cache_dir = 'carrierwave'
```